# Saving attachments in Outlook emails using python

Tags: python, email, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to scan my outlook inbox based on subject and sender email and then trying to download any attached files locally in a specific location.

This code currently runs forever without detecting an email with the desired sender address and subject.

```
import win32com.client
import re

# set up connection to outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
while True:
  try:
    current_sender = str(message.Sender).lower()
    current_subject = str(message.Subject).lower()
    if re.search('The Subject I am scanning for',current_subject) != None and re.search('the sender email address to scan for',current_sender) != None:
      print(current_subject) 
      print(current_sender)  
      attachments = message.Attachments
      attachment = attachments.Item(1)
      attachment_name = str(attachment).lower()
      attachment.SaveASFile("Y:"+"\\" +"STRATEGIES"+"\\" + attachment_name)
    else:
      pass
    message = messages.GetNext()
  except:
    message = messages.GetNext()
exit
```

Ideally, once the download of the attachemnt of the specific email is comepleted, the email would be placed in my archive folder which is in index 39.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not loop through all messages in a fodler - use `Items.FindFirst/FindsNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

Secondly, `MailItem.Sender` is an object, not a string. When you cast it to a string, it gets converted using the default property (which is `Name`). What you want is `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`.

In the future, you really need to step through your code and look at the values of the variables to see if they are what you expect.